# jQuery tabbing for multiple content sections

Tags: jquery

I have been trying to modify a jQuery tabs tutorial so that I can have a kind of tabbing area that has two separate content sections for each tab, but can't get the second content area to work. Any guidance in the right direction would be very much appreciated.

[DEMO](http://codepen.io/simmo85/pen/dELwK)

Comment: You could try out jQuery UI tabs.

http://jqueryui.com/tabs/

Or bootstrap

http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#tabs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look this [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/KUW7H/6/) link this will help you to get the jquery tab with two content areas.

```
$('#tabs li').mouseover(function(){
        num = $('#tabs li').index(this);
        $('#container .tabs').hide().eq(num).show();
        $('#container-2 .tabs').hide().eq(num).show();
});
```

I hope this will help you more. All the best.

Comment: Awesome, just what I was after! Thanks so much for your help.